# How to call activity from widget -- Android

Tags: android

Thanks for previous replies,
I am doing application with widget, my idea is to open a activity when click the widget. i uesed this piece of code to get the activity

```
try {
    WidgetActivity.Widget.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    Toast.makeText(context, "Update Widget", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.toString();
}
Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, Test.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

but i am getting forceclose error. i am new to widget concept. i am not sure where to put call the start activity method. Pls guide me

Comment: why don't you put a PendingIntent on your RemoteView when creating the widget? That's the standard method and is widely available on any Widget tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html) for AppWidgets.  Specifically the part where `onUpdate()` is discussed, as the example shows how to call an `Activity` from the widget.

Comment: i did like  intent = new Intent(context, Test.class);
             PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
             RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
             views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_textview, pendingIntent); but the activity is not called

Comment: Are you sure that `R.layout.main` is the layout of your widget and not your activity?  I think you also need to call `updateAppWidget` afterwards.

Comment: Thanks dave, Noo, Its not layout of widget. Seems very much confused to start new activity from widget.Is it possible to start Home page of the app(ie different class of activity) by clicking widget.

Comment: It needs to be the layout of your widget.  Read the documentation or like @Budius suggested try any of the [tutorials](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidWidgets/article.html) [online](http://ericosgood.com/prog/android-appwidget-tutorial/)